# Вызов в html-странице Vue, который находится в отдельном файле

Tags: vue.js

Гуглю, гуглю, но так и не могу найти хорошее объяснение на вопрос, как банально имея html-страницу вызвать код Vue, который я хочу вынести в отдельный файл. Простым подключением файла не обойдешься. Объясните пожалуйста механизм вызова! Пытался понять суть import, export файлов Vue. Но не получилось. 
Буду благодарен любой помощи!

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#idSignIn",
        methods: {
            onPress: () => {
                return $.ajax({
                    url: '/Users/checkLogAndPas/',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        USER_LOGIN: document.getElementById('idLogin').value,
                        USER_PASSWORD: document.getElementById('idPassword').value
                    },
                    success: (data) => {
                        console.log("OK", data);
                    },
                    error: (data) => {
                        console.log("Error", data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Моя разметка

```
<div class="col-lg-4 panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading"><div class="sidebar-header"> Вход </div></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="idLogin" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Логин">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="idPassword" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Пароль" v-model="password">
            </div>
            <button id="idSignIn" type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" v-on:click="onPress"> Вход </button>
            <button id="idRegistration" type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-left"> Регистрация </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: нужно подключить скрипт с vue - https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Хотелось бы сразу оговориться, что код в `js` файлах не оборачивается в тег `script`.

#### Сборка приложений vuejs без webpack

**Недостатки** - сложно обновлять зависимости, нет модульной поддержки CSS, в большинстве редакторов нет подсветки шаблонов (`templates` поле). Таким приложениям не хватает минимизации кода.

**index.html**

```
<div id="app">
    <router-link to="/">Главная страница</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about">О сайте</router-link>

    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>

    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@3.0.6"></script>

<!-- Подключаем как обычные js файлы. -->
<script src="./components/home.js"></script>
<script src="./components/about.js"></script>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
```

**home.js**

```
const Home = {
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  template: `<div class="container"><h2>Домашняя страница</h2></div>`
}
```

**about.js**

```
const About = {
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  template: `<div class="container"><h2>Страница о сайте</h2></div>`
}
```

**main.js**

```
const Router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    }, {
      path: '/about',
      component: About
    }],
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: Router,
  data: {
    msg: 'Название сайта'
  }
})
```

Т.е. ничего особенного: создаём один экземпляр приложения `vuejs`; объявляем константами компоненты в разных `js` файлах и в `main.js` их используем.

#### Модульная система [import/export]

**Недостатки** - браузерная поддержка. Еще хуже обстоят дела с [динамическим импортом ES6](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import) - 78.17% на 2019.05.10. Подробнее об [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). Поэтому ES-модули используются в сочетании с системами сборки, такими как [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/).

**index.html**

```
<div id="app">
    <router-link to="/">Главная страница</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about">О сайте</router-link>

    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>

    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@3.0.6"></script>

<!-- Подключаем ч/з `import/export`, указав `type="module"`. -->
<script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Home from './components/home.js'
const About = () => import('./components/about.js')

const Router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    }, {
      path: '/about',
      component: About
    }],
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: Router,
  data: {
    msg: 'Название сайта'
  }
})
```

**home.js**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  template: `<div class="container"><h2>Домашняя страница</h2></div>`
}
```

**about.js**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  template: `<div class="container"><h2>Страница о сайте</h2></div>`
}
```

---

Все эти недостатки решаются [однофайловыми компонентами с расширением `.vue`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-JavaScript), использование которых позволяют такие инструменты как Webpack и Browserify.

**NB** `home.js` !== `home.vue`.

**NB** import/export в ES - не тоже самое, что в Node.js.

Comment: Ого, какой прекрасный ответ!